# Input button click event not firing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why my code is not executing. I am simply assigning textbox value to paragraph's innerHTML on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Error handling</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("btnName").click(function () {
                var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
                x.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                alert("Done");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtName" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input id="btnName" type="button" value="Try It" />
    <p id="Demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("btnName")` should be `$(#btnName")`

Comment: where is your jquery script tag?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek  Sorry. But still same problem.nothing happened.

Comment: Sorry. nothing happened :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Error handling</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnName").click(function () {
            var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
            x.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            alert("Done");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="txtName" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="btnName" type="button" value="Try It" />
<p id="Demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works and also saves time from downloading  and adding jquery reference script manually.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery takes CSS-like selectors to find and manipulate elements.

Your code should read like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnName').click(...)
})
```

Comment: Sorry. nothing happened.

Comment: DMKE's answer should fix your problem, but you have another one: you're not referencing jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$("btnName").click(function () {
```

Should be:

```
$("#btnName").click(function () {
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/nXKsk/).

Also you need to import the jQuery Library (in the `<head>` tag):

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry. nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$("#btnName");
```

instead of

```
$("btnName");
```

By the way, you can use Jquery all the long:

```
$('#Demo').html($('#txtName').val());
```

Comment: Sorry. nothing happened.

Comment: as other people say you should include Jquery in your headers and you can use JQuery all the way: `x.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtName").value;`  should be : `$('#Demo').html($('#txtName').val());`

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Error handling</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnName").click(function () {
                var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
                x.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                alert("Done");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtName" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input id="btnName" type="button" value="Try It" />
    <p id="Demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer but I stumbled upon it when I encountered a button click event not firing which used to work. We switched our site from html 4 to html 5 and it caused some issues so I think this one is related. The button ID was "MakeInvoice" and I changed it to "MakeInvoiceBtn" and it started working again so I think there was an ID conflict that html 5 would not forgive but the earlier html we used was ok with.